# Execute JS file from Xcode without UIWebView

Tags: javascript, jquery, xcode, odata

I have a JS file that makes a OData call, is possible run this file from xcode without a weview? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In iOS9 Apple introduced the SafariViewController that allows you to interface with web stuff in your app.

Here's a [link to apples site and the wwdc video on it](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=504)

I haven't used it but have been told that there isn't a lot of room for customization so that might not help you.  However, there is also WKWebView and the WKWebKit framework that was introduced in iOS 8.  This is very similar to UIWebview but has more functionality and utilizes WebKit API

Here's a [link to apple's docs page about it](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/) and an in [depth look at it from NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/)